# How I create a database for a list of users' interested topics?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, categories

For the site I'm working on, I want a user to have the ability to checkmark multiple boxes that represent things he/she might be interested, similar to StumbleUpon.  A user would check 'web development' and 'web design' then click 'Submit', which would then store his preferences in a database.

Later, if somebody created a project that was tagged with one of the preferences he selected, that user would get an update.  So if I made a new project that said "Building a Website" and checked the category "web development", all users who had "web development" selected on their personal profiles would get some kind of message or email alerting them to the newly created topic.

What is the best way to implement this in MySQL format?  I looked at some pages on managing hierarchical data (there will be generalized categories like "Computers" or "Music" and an admin will be able to add/delete/edit categories), but none of the methods seemed to be what I needed - at least, not in the way of thinking I'm stuck in.  Perhaps there's an easier answer out there that I've been overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a table containing the various interests. Say

```
Interests :- id, interest
```

Then a table which stores all the interests selected by a user as

```
UserInterests :- user_id, interest_id
```

And a project interest relation as

```
ProjectInterest :- project_id, interest_id
```

Now when a new project is added you can run a query similar to the following onw to get the users that the project is of interest

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM UserInterests ui, ProjectInterests pi 
WHERE ui.interest_id = pi.interest_id AND pi.project_id = <new project id>
```

Or, using the explicit join syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM UserInterests ui
  INNER JOIN ProjectInterests pi ON ui.interest_id = pi.interest_id
WHERE pi.project_id = <new project id>
```

Comment: DISTINCT always applies to the entire row, not to a particular column, so there's no need to add brackets around the column name, like `DISTINCT(user_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking - I think - is how to implement a many-to-many relationship.
The problem is that you can't give a user a list of interests without locking yourself into an exact number of interests they can select.

The solution is a [Junction Table](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Junction_table). On one hand, you have your list of users, and on the other hand, you have your list of interests. The junction table is a third table that lists the relationship between these two groups.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_interest` (
    userid UNSIGNED INT REFERENCES `user` (userid),
    interestid UNSIGNED INT REFERENCES `interests` (interestid),
    PRIMARY KEY (interestid, userid)
)
```

Now you have a list of UNIQUE combinations of users and interests. Let's say you have a list of news articles, each with a single topic ("interestid") assigned to it. Now you can do something like,

```
SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE `article`.`interestid` IN (
  SELECT `interestid` FROM `user_interest` WHERE `userid` = X
)
```

Which will retrieve the list of articles related to user X's selected interests. First, you get the list of topics that were related to your specified user, then you get the list of articles with matching topics.